# Initialize a struct's string data member with the structs non-type variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to make a struct that receives non-type variadic template arguments. I'm trying to make it initialize a string that is a data member of this struct with these template arguments, like so:

```
    template <char... Chs>
    struct MyStruct
    {
        string d_text;
    };

    int main()
    {
         cout << MyStruct<'a','b'>().d_text << '\n';
    }
```

What should the constructor of `MyStruct` do in order to initialize `d_text` according to my requirement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your question is about initializing `d_text`, you can use `std::string`s [`std::initializer_list<char>` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), along with a parameter pack expansion.

```
template <char... Chs>
struct MyStruct
{
    string d_text;
    MyStruct() : d_text({Chs...}){}
};
```

[Coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/defb797da99c7ceb)